# Modding Lua script for a game, Sintax and Assets, Transport Fever 2

Tags: lua

I am attempting to mod a basic lua script. Under the below code, where **"lineInfo.itemsTransported.PASSENGERS" "then: P"** is renaming things in game based on whether or not I am selecting a **Cargo** or **Passenger** vehicle. I would like the system to signify whether or not I am selecting a "**train**" or "**truck**"

Modding instruction manual: https://www.transportfever2.com/wiki/doku.php?id=modding:scriptingbasics

I know how to modify and read lua code, to a degree. But I don't know how to reference another asset. I have read through a good portion of the modding wiki, but as a lehman, I don't know if I should be referencing syntax, or assets, or what its called what Im looking for. Thank you for the help.

````
    ////////highlighted section of code first, whole script including snippet below



    if (lineInfo.itemsTransported.PASSENGERS ~= nil) then

            newLineName = "P"
        else
            newLineName = "C"
            isCargo = true
            inner = false
        end```

    //////// whole code from here down //////////////////////

 
    ```function data()
    return {
        guiInit = function()
            local text = api.gui.comp.TextView.new("Rename Lines")
            text:setId("mainMenuLeft.LineRename.button.text")
            local lineRenameButton = api.gui.comp.Button.new(text, true)
            lineRenameButton:setId("mainMenuLeft.LineRename.button")
            local mainMenuLeftLayout = api.gui.util.getById("mainMenuLeftLayout")
            local numItems = mainMenuLeftLayout:getNumItems()
            mainMenuLeftLayout:addItem(lineRenameButton)

            lineRenameButton:onClick(
                function ()
                    
                    local lineList = api.gui.comp.Table.new(1, "MULTI")
                    local text = api.gui.comp.TextView.new("Rename Line")
                    local renameButton = api.gui.comp.Button.new(text, true)
                    local lines = api.engine.system.lineSystem.getLines()
                    local lineHeaderTextView = api.gui.comp.TextView.new("Name")
                    local textViewList = {}
                    lineList:setHeader({lineHeaderTextView})
                    for i, line in ipairs(lines) do
                        local lineInfo = game.interface.getEntity(line)
                        local lineTextView = api.gui.comp.TextView.new(lineInfo.name)
                        lineTextView:addStyleClass("table-item")
                        lineList:addRow({lineTextView})
                        textViewList[i] = lineTextView
                
                    end
                    local layout = api.gui.layout.BoxLayout.new("VERTICAL")
                    local scrollArea = api.gui.comp.ScrollArea.new(lineList,"ScrollTable")
                    local size = api.gui.util.Size.new(300,800)
                    scrollArea:setMaximumSize(size)
                    layout:addItem(scrollArea)
                    layout:addItem(renameButton)
                    local win = api.gui.comp.Window.new("Rename Lines", layout)
                    win:addHideOnCloseHandler()
                    renameButton:onClick(
                        function()
                            local selectedLines = lineList:getSelected()
                            for i, lineIndex in ipairs(selectedLines) do
                                if(type(lines[lineIndex+1]) == "number") then
                                    local newName = renameLine(lines[lineIndex+1])
                                    textViewList[lineIndex+1]:setText(newName)
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    )
                end
            )
        end
        }
    end```

    function renameAllLines()
    local lines = api.engine.system.lineSystem.getLines()
    for i, line in ipairs(lines) do
        renameLine(line)
    end
    end

    function renameLine(line)
    local inner = true
    local isCargo = false
    local lineInfo = game.interface.getEntity(line)
    local newLineName = lineInfo.name
    if #lineInfo.stops > 0 then
        if (lineInfo.itemsTransported.PASSENGERS ~= nil) then
            newLineName = "P"
        else
            newLineName = "C"
            isCargo = true
            inner = false
        end

        local prevName = ""

        for i, stop in ipairs(lineInfo.stops) do
            local townStop = game.interface.getEntity(stop).stations[1]
            local stopName = game.interface.getEntity(stop).name
            local town = api.engine.system.stationSystem.getTown(townStop)
            local townName = api.engine.getComponent(town, api.type.ComponentType.NAME).name
            if isCargo and string.find(stopName, "Street") == nil then
                newLineName = newLineName .. "-" .. stopName
                prevName = stopName
            else
                if prevName ~= townName then
                    if i > 1 then
                        inner = false
                    end
                    newLineName = newLineName .. "-" .. townName
                    prevName = townName
                end
            end
        end

        if inner then
            newLineName = newLineName .. " " .. "Inner"
        end
        api.cmd.sendCommand(api.cmd.make.setName(line, newLineName))
    end
    return newLineName
    end`
````

Comment: what is an asset in this context? I'm not sure what you're asking for. please improve your post. read [ask], take the [tour]

Comment: you use ``` in your large code block was that intended to be markdown formatting for multiple smaller code blocks? or is it actually part of your code?